# Getting the two highest order terms in the sum $\sum_{j=0}^n j^k \left(\frac{n^2}{j(n-2)}\right)^j$

Tags: asymptotics

How to get the two highest order terms in 
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n j^k \left(\frac{n^2}{j(n-2)}\right)^j, $$
where $k\in \mathbb{N}$, leaving the rest in big Oh of something.

I think this sum equals
$$ n^k \left( \frac{n^2}{n-2}\right)^n + \mathcal{O}\left(n^{k-1} \left( \frac{n^2}{n-2}\right)^n\right),$$
but I don't know how to show it, and I need the first two terms.

Comment: I think your estimate is far too large. Assuming I can replace the sum with its corresponding integral, I get $$\sum_{j=0}^n j^k \left(\frac{n^2}{j(n-2)}\right)^j \sim \exp\!\left(\frac{n}{e}+\frac{2}{e}-\frac{1}{2}-k\right)n^{k+1/2}\sqrt{2\pi}$$ by a rough application of the Laplace method. Is this for a class? I think getting the next term this way would be difficult, so if it is for a class then perhaps there is another way. For example, there may be a nice probabilistic interpretation for the sum.